# Dynamically populate HTML table?

Tags: html, database, dynamic, html-table

Up till now I was doing small tables, max 10x10, for which I made a double loop with a DB query inside that's looking for specific data which that certain `<td>` field should contain.

Now I've stumbled upon much bigger table, and I'm starting to wonder will it be OK to continue this practice, or should I first draw the whole table and then fill it afterwards. If this is the right way, which technique should I use that will allow me to access to DB, identify table row and table column in the existing HTML table, and populate them afterwards?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Usually, this is done with a URL parameter (typically named "offset" or "page"). As of right now, though, you haven't asked a very concrete question, so it's impossible to give a very concrete answer.

Comment: I was asking if it's better to query a DB thousand times, always get one data and write it to HTML table while forming it, or to make just one query, and then fill already formed HTML table? Or third option.?

Comment: Query the table once, definitely. Database queries are expensive; the fewer the better. Do one query, then build your table. The best way to do that depends on the language you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what programming language language you are using, your pagination, filtering, sorting requirements.

If you are a beginner you can try out the below mentioned plugins which would simplify most of your works.

https://datatables.net/

http://www.jqwidgets.com/

For tables with large amount of data, displaying the plain HTML table would be a bad idea. Just try the above plugins.

Comment: I'm using PHP. I know how to get the data from database, but I'm not sure what to do next. I can make a select query that would get the data from DB, but can AJAX handle multiple consecutive responses and search for certain <td>'s in order to fill the table?

Comment: Firstly, if you know how to get the data from db, you can loop it and echo it to the HTML table. Just do one query and loop through the result of that query and construct the HTML table along with data. Why do you need AJAX for that ?

Comment: Because data is random. Imagine you have list of food in the database, and you have a HTML table inside which it should be grouped. So you make a cell named:meat, and inside it you put couple of DB entries like goat (from line 44), pork (from line 72), fish (line 2), etc... So if I start reading data from DB, I would have to return to previous <td>'s to update them.

Comment: Then in that case, you could do separate queries with different filter for each <td> and fill the table. That would be best.